# WebSphere Liberty P12 fails to enable TLS

Tags: ssl, curl, websphere-liberty, server.xml, p12

When trying to enable SSL/TLS on WebSphere Liberty profile, WLP fails to allow SSL connectivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="DefaultServer">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="/opt/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/wildcard.p12" type="PKCS12" password="******"/>
    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9080"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
        <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

</server>
```

When issuing `curl https://localhost:9443 --insecure -vv` I get the following response. This doesn't happen if I use the default generated `<keyStore id="defautlKeyStore" password="somePassword"/>`

```
[~] curl https://localhost:9443 --insecure -vv

   About to connect() to localhost port 9443 (#0)
   Trying ::1...
   Connected to localhost (::1) port 9443 (#0)
   Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
   NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
   Encountered end of file
   Closing connection 0
   curl: (35) Encountered end of file
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

Some .p12 attribute data. Note, the .p12 displayed below has private key and cert omitted.

```
MAC verified OK
Bag Attributes
    Microsoft Local Key set: <No Values>
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: <omitted for Stack Overflow Post>
    Microsoft CSP Name: Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Key Attributes
    X509v3 Key Usage: 10
```

Comment: logs and verbose output from the client? Otherwise it's guessing.

Comment: Also helps if you can describe the content of your p12.

Comment: @covener which client are you referring to? curl? browser? and what content are you looking for in the p12?

Comment: The client in your test is curl. The p12 contains 1 or more certs with which are likely related to eachother -- perhaps you could show which one you expect to be used as your servers x509 cert and show it's a complete trust chain? Really anything you can describe about it.